# Invariant Violation: injectTapEventPlugin(): Can only be called once per application lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I need this library for the deprecated onTouchTap for Material UI. Apparently I can only run this "injectTapEventPlugin()" one time in the whole span of the application so I put it in the constructor in my APP.js file. However, it still ended up calling it twice.

Anybody with more React experience: where is the optimal placement for this function and import statement?

Comment: please let me have a look at your code

Answer (score 1):

You can check out how the material-ui docs site does it here:

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/app/app.js#L14

We put it in the same file that renders the app into the DOM.